# How to intercept a method which is called within the same class?

Tags: jakarta-ee

I found EJB Interceptors can work well to intercept the methods that are called by other classes. However, when a method is called by another method of the same class, EJB Interceptor will not be fired.

Comment: What interceptors are you talking about?  Are you using a specific framework that supports interceptors?  You'll have to mention what that is.  Because what you asking for cannot be done in pure Java.

Comment: @sstan the question is tagged log4j, although I do agree that perhaps the poster could include more details about how they are currently going about this implementation so we can better answer the question

Comment: @Beau Bouchard: Log4j is the library he wants to use to code his logger interceptor, I get that.  But which framework is providing the interceptor service?  The answer is certainly not Log4j. Is it Spring? Java EE?, other?

Comment: Sorry for making any confusion. I'm talking about JavaEE. By annotating on class or method level, the interceptor can catch any callings which made out of the targeted (annotated) method's class. However, what I'm trying to do is to intercept all callings of the annotated method, and ignore wherever the callings are from. Hopefully, this can help with clarifying the question. Thanks for any comments.

Answer (score -1):

Look into AspectJ. It can intercept calls and has a very powerful method of describing when to intercept.  e.g.  Intercept all calls to System.getProperty() from any classes in the com.example.foo package.